# How does IE determine whether a site is an internet or an intranet site?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

Within IE, people are provided with security setting dialog to decide whether a website is rendered as an internet or an intranet site.

My question is how do you tell the current page you loaded is a internet or intranet in IE 9 or 10?
Since I could not find the status bar like those ones in IE 7 or 8

Comment: Find this link to explain everything. [link]http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_7/status-bar-in-ie10-no-longer-shows-what-security/c8be69fe-efb7-4034-b369-e5d46f3945e8

Comment: why did I get reputation deducted?

Comment: It answers to "how do you tell?", but not to "how does IE determine?" (from the title). Regarding the second question: you have 3 up votes + 1 downvote. Probably this is why you had a "reputation deducted".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can look in File -> Properties. 
Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to display the menu bar if it's not there.

There you can see "Local intranet" or "Internet".

[image]